# Extend Visual studio Solution Right Click menu with new button

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-addins

I want to add a new button to the menu when you right click on a solution. I want to add a button to to custom things with TFS and building and would like for it to be available when you right click on a solution. Currently there are several buttons for building cleaning etc. I am able to get a button onto the solution explorer toolbar (Circled in red) but would like to have it appear in the other menu (in the red square) Any help would be appreciated. 
I followed this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb166773.aspx) to get to where I am at now. Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can tell you how to add commands to that context menu: under the Tools menu -> Customize, in the Commands tab, click "Context menu:", find "Project and Solution Context Menus | Solution" in the extremely long and unwieldy dropdown, then hit Add Command... and add the command you want in that menu.

I've only used that information to add a macro (to replace the native "Open Containing Folder" command with one that used a different file manager), I've never tried to create my own command that wasn't a macro, but I expect if you were able to get custom Commands in custom buttons, you might also be able to find them in the Add Command dialog as well?

Comment: Thanks that got me on the correct path, was able to make an addin and apply it that way.

Comment: Thats a bad way from my opinion. If I take myself the time to code an extension for visual studio, I work on it until it is well rounded. That said, it has to decide for its own on installation where it has to show up. Thats a real extension. This one is like doing things by halves.